# In Rust, why is '[T]' and 'str' slice type not a syntax error?

Tags: arrays, string, rust, slice

From what I understand, `&[T]` type is a 'fat' pointer (memory address and size) and not the slice itself and `[T]` is the actual slice that is being referenced. But why didn't they make `[T]` a syntax error in the context below?

```rust
let y: [i32; 6] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

// let z: [i32] = y[..]; // error: the size for values of type `[i32]` cannot be known at compilation time

let z: &[i32] = &y[..]; // OK

// let v: str = "Hello World"; // the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
```

From the error: `[i32] cannot be known at compilation`, is this just an error to make me, the user, understand why this syntax isn't possible or is it because I'm not using this syntax right and it is valid in some context?

Comment: And what is supposed to be the type of `z` ?

Comment: sorry i mistyped some code, fixed it. `x` was supposed to be `y`. The commented out `z` is supposed to be `[i32]`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret strictly speaking `[T]` is in fact an actual slice type, though colloquially `&[T]` is also called a slice: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/slice.html

Comment: Why are you asking for a *syntax* error exactly? Just because something does not make *semantic* sense does not mean it is invalid syntax.

Comment: `feature(unsized_locals)` may eventually make this *syntactically* valid code also *semantically* valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is possible to use unsized types like `str`, `[T]`, and `dyn MyTrait` in some contexts.

The most common at the moment is in generics.  You can, for example, have a `Box<[T]>` or `Box<str>`, `Arc<[T]>`, or any generic with a `?Sized` bound.

There's also a few in-development features using such unsized types:

- [You can define a `struct` with one unsized field, making the struct itself unsized.](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/sizedness-in-rust.md#user-defined-unsized-types) Pretty useless at the moment though, since you can't actually create such a structure.
- [RFC-1909](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1909-unsized-rvalues.md), when implemented, will allow you to use unsized types on the stack, in args, etc. by allocating them dynamically on the stack. I wouldn't count on it happening anytime soon though.

Answer (score 2):

> But why didn't they make [T] a syntax error in the context below?

Because there's nothing about the syntax that has any reason to be invalid?

While DSTs are difficult to work with and don't make sense everywhere, there are contexts in which they are perfectly legal e.g.

```
struct Foo {
    a: usize,
    b: [i32]
}
```